# External Enclosure for 2 SAS HDDs

Tags: hard-disk, raid, drive-enclosure, sas

I picked up a couple SAS HDDs that I would like to place in an external enclosure. However, I am struggling to find any that supports SAS HDDs. Does this exist? Could you please recommend any? I would ideally like that enclosure to support JBOD or RAID 0/1 and have a USB interface. Anything below $200 would be alright. No other constraints (power / size / noise). A simple search did not yield any results.

Comment: Uhmm, eclosures... I tried to buy a JBOD for 8 SATA. It is just plastic and a standard power unit. The cheapest is about $300 on the ebay... and everybody wants to sell s..t NAS servers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can just amazon "external sas".

for example "HighPoint RocketStor 6414S 6Gb/s SAS/SATA 4-Bay Storage Tower Enclosure" for $289.

you are not likely to find anything *economical*, not with SAS.  SAS is server work environment, not for home use.  If you *picked up a couple sas disks* you may want to just cut your losses now if this is for personal use.  You will still need to get something like an SFF-8086 external sas cable  to connect the sas enclosure to your computer, and then you will need an internal pcie SAS [raid] card within your pc- brand new a genuine dell of lsi/avago can run you $1000 depending where you buy it from otherwise you can get lucky finding one for $100 on amazon.  A used Dell PERC H730P for $245 i see on amazon.  But you will need to cobble it all together, and you take your chances.

you would be better off amazon'ing a **SATA** external where 4+ TB is the norm now and very economical.  Even if you got those sas disk(s) for free, it's not worth it when sata disk prices are as low as they are.

note: SAS hardware can support sata disks... sata disks can plug into a sas backplane and they make SAS-to-SATA breakout cables.  But a SAS disk cannot plug into a SATA connector.  And be aware there are various SFF-#### cables supporting sas so you have to make sure all your hardware can plug into each other.